# Apply query total for variable

Tags: yii2

I have sum query with active record, and assign with total filed.

I select one record is ok, so show as ActiveDataProvider, that total not show.

This my query:

```
$sumQuery = 'sum(Condition) total';
```

And select sum:

```
 $query->select(['*', $sumQuery]);
```

So how can i get it's in Data Provinder.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sumQuery = new yii\db\Expression('sum(Condition) AS total');

$query->select(['*', $sumQuery]);
```

Also, I think you have to declare the **$total** in your model class.

Answer (score 0):

Or try

```
 $query->select('*, sum(Condition) as total');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $model->find()->select(['*, sum(Condition) as total']);
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query' => $query,
]);
```

And, for example, in GridView columns its will be exist like this:

```
[
     'attribute' => 'total',
]
```